# GORC - program for converting image to text

Tags: image, text

How to use GORC please?

http://jocr.sourceforge.net/download.html

I tried:

```
djpeg -pnm -gray 2.jpg | gocr
 Optical Character Recognition --- gocr 0.49 20100924
 Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Joerg Schulenburg  GPG=1024D/53BDFBE3
 released under the GNU General Public License
 use option -h for help
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50
```

I would like to convert *.jpg to *.text.

After an advise I did:

Thank you I did:

```
convert 2.png 2.jpg

djpeg -pnm -gray 2.jpg | gocr

 Optical Character Recognition --- gocr 0.49 20100924
 Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Joerg Schulenburg  GPG=1024D/53BDFBE3
 released under the GNU General Public License
 use option -h for help
```

How to create *.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear like your JPG file isn't actually a JPG - 0x89 0x50 are the start of a PNG file signature (`<0x89>PNG`). Try converting it to JPG (either manually or via ImageMagick if you are getting such files from somewhere)